# Is there any way to change IntelliJ Kotlin coding style to catch extra white space after a function or at the end of the file?

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to change the formatting of files within IntelliJ using Kotlin formatting from code that looks like this:

```
class Class {
    class InnerClass {
    }

}
EOF
```

To something like this:

```
class Class {
    class InnerClass {
    }
}

EOF
```

I would love to be able to have my code reformatting catch this kind of thing but I can't seem to find it in the settings or even mentioned anywhere online. If you go into settings->editor->Kotlin->Blank Lines you do find similar settings but not quite what I'm looking for. The similar settings I found were here:
[image: settings]

Comment: Keep Maximum Blank Lines Before '}' is exactly the setting you're looking for. Set it to 0.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a setting for having exactly 1 empty line at the end of the file?

Comment: I should also mentioned it does add 1 on save if there is none but doesn't cut it down if there is more than one.

Comment: There is a setting for ensuring there's at least one empty line (Editor | General | [x] Ensure line feed at file end on Save), but there isn't any setting for removing multiple blank lines.